# ADB Error 21, signature error. Would I be able to solve my problem using fastboot? If so, any recommendations about how to set it up

Tags: android, adb

My phone is turning off when it emits random sounds. The problem is that when it is turning on, it emits a sound causing it to turn off lol. So now I am trying to use ADB to mute it.

I downloaded the SDK package and tried to run `adb shell input keyevent 164` through a bat file. But I keep getting error 21, signature error. I read a bit and it seems that I need to be on fastboot mode rather than the recovery mode, tho in the fastboot screen there isn't an ADB option and I got a bit lost. My phone is also not recognized when using fastboot devices command. Even if I make it available, would I be able to mute it?

Comment: When you are in fastboot/bootloader mode, then adb will not work, unless you leave fastboot mode https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221635/2241. Also in recovery adb if available is usually limited to side loading. Even if full adb commands would work, recovery is a separate OS, changes you make there have no effect on the main OS. BTW: your story about sounds causing a reboot is strange. Are you sure the sound is not an effect of the reboot? What have you done to get these sounds? Finally you are a bit OT here better ask here https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the links! I will write there later. And also for the explanation, seems It is a bit more complicated than I thought. The starting sound is standard of the phone model. But yes, kinda weird problem. Though I didnt explain it right, by emiting I meant reproducing the sound, and depending of the sound pitch it turns off the phone